# No property, bindable property, or event found for 'HeightRequest' for Button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an IOS Application with embedded Xamarin Forms. I created a simple view with buttons and want to set the height of these buttons depending on the platform. This is my code:

```
        <Button Text="{Binding SendFeedbackButtonText}"
                Command="{Binding SendEarlyFeedbackCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Margin="3,0,3,0" >
            <Button.Effects>
                <effects:PrimaryButtonEffect />
            </Button.Effects>
            <Button.HeightRequest>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="37"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Button.HeightRequest>
        </Button>
```

But this gives me the following error in build:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'HeightRequest', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

When I set HeightRequest fix in the button tag it works.

Xamarin.Forms version: 2.5.0.121934

Also I created a new blank App with Xamarin.Forms and .net standard 2.0 to try this out. It works as long as you don't have the XamlCompilation Attribute set:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

You can find the project here: https://github.com/NPadrutt/FormsButtonIssueTestProject

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Forms try switching it to this instead

```
<Button.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="37"/>
</Button.HeightRequest>
```

or

```
<Button.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="iOS">37</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</Button.HeightRequest>
```

Comment: That produces the same issue unfortunately. Also the Platform Properties (e.g. Android, iOS and WinPhone) are marked as obsolete.

Comment: If that doesn't work then it may be a problem with Xamarin.Forms embedding

Comment: But it is already during compilation time. If it is an issue with embedding that would happen during runtime in my understand.

Comment: Your right. I updated my answer the syntax is a bit different with the new `Device.RuntimePlatform`

Comment: unfortunately the same result. I guess the value="" field is the same as when you write it to the content of the tag.

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me fine when I try in a normal forms app and it is the correct way to do it based on [James Montemagno's blog post](https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/). Maybe try removing the effect or changing versions of forms.

Comment: I created a test project (link is in the original post). Have you tested it with or without the XamlCompilation Attribute? Which version of Xamarin Forms have you used?

Comment: I just tried it with xaml comp on and off, which didn't make a difference. Also, the project I edited to try is still on a slightly older version of forms 2.4.0.38779

Comment: Also, it wasn't in a .NET standard library that based on your test project is what I'm thinking the culprit is

Comment: you're right. there is an issue for that topic in github repository of Xamarin Forms: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1368

Comment: or this one (probably even better) https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1316